# Android - How to use custom font for a text view in popup window

Tags: android, popup

I am trying to use custom font for a textview in popup window. i tried the following code

```
    String fontPath1 = "icons.ttf";

    TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath1);
    txt1.setTypeface(tf1);
```

It works on a separate activity. How to integrate this code in popup window.

instr Layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/instruction"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/greenbg"
         android:padding="8dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"  >

          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/intro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/intro3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>  

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/int1"
              android:layout_below="@id/intro"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center|left" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/symbol1"
                android:background="@drawable/rulebg2"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:gravity="center|center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/intr1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my popup java code:

```
Button inst= (Button) findViewById(R.id.instr);
    inst.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
              .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.instr, null);  
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow( popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);  

                     Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
                     btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              popupWindow.dismiss();
             }});

                     popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

           }});
```

Comment: Can you please post the content of `R.layout.instr`?

Comment: You can use a Custom Dialog (Google for it).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this with your PopupWindow's layout?

```
TextView text1 = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text1.setTypeface(tf1);
```